# What is wrong with my aloe vera?

Tags: flowers

My aloe vera's leaves are dying. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? 
[image][image][image]

Comment: Please give us more information.   What did it look like vs what it looks like now?  What is it doing that you say it is dying?  You show one old leaf shrivelling up, which could just be its natural course.  I would say that it does not get enough sunlight.  I don't think it's an Aloe vera, but Aloiampelos ciliaris - Climbing Aloe.

Comment: I don't have photos how it looked before. Its leaves are yellowing that's what gives me the impression that it is dying. I water it once every 2-3 weeks now in winter, and it doesn't really get a lot of sunlight but there's nowhere else I can put it. What should I do in these conditions? Thank you

Comment: Don't water it on a schedule, water it after the soil goes bone dry or the leaves start to curl.  Because you don't have significant light I would tend to keep it on the dry side, never soaking the soil.   If the plant is loosing a few lower leaves that should be expected especially if it's not getting enough light.   If it is loosing lots of leaves, I would find it some light.  Buy a small desk lamp grow light.  Something like this https://www.amazon.ca/Wolezek-Spectrum-Dimmable-Hydroponics-Succulent/dp/B07TD7VGDR/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=desktop+grow+light&qid=1578180776&sr=8-9

Comment: That one is bendable so you could shine some light on the upper part of the plant and some on the lower leaves as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it is dying.  I believe it is loosing lower leaves, because it is not getting enough sunlight.  If you do not have a window, buy a small desk top grow light.  One with that is full spectrum and white light (no red/blue lights).   Something like the link below. It's about $35 in Canada, it will be about $10 cheaper if you are in the States.

I would also recommend you keep your plant on the dry side.  As long as it is not getting some good sunlight.  If you do buy the grow light you can water it normally, let the soil dry out or the leaves curl a little before you give it a good soak.  Keeping it on the dry side means never giving it a soak. Just enough water to survive until it can get outside for the summer.

There are other methods you can use. I am sure others will share. These are the ones that have worked for me.

I already told you this, you have a Aloiampelos ciliaris, not a Aloe vera.  The care is similar.  You can still use the leaves for burns.

[Desk top grow light](https://www.amazon.ca/Wolezek-Spectrum-Dimmable-Hydroponics-Succulent/dp/B07TD7VGDR/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=desktop%20grow%20light&qid=1578180776&sr=8-9)